# Allowing tiff/tiff image files in Magento admin product image uploader

Tags: image, magento, magento-1.7, tiff

How do I allow tif/tiff files in the product image gallery uploader in Magento admin? I've already tried updating {Package}_Adminhtml_Block_Media_Uploader::__construct() with the following code:

```
$this->getConfig()->setFilters(array(
        'images' => array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Images (.gif, .jpg, .png, .tif)'),
            'files' => array('*.gif', '*.jpg', '*.png', '*.tif', '*.tiff')
        ),
```

Though the uploader browse popup still filters/grays out tif's.

I've confirmed my local class is correctly overriding core. I also located xml config for file extensions in the CMS module, but that obiviously is not related here (right?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with tiff is, that GD2 is not able to do anything with this format. Therefore you need to change the Image_Adapter, e.g. to this:

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Perfect_Watermarks

and afterwards you have to rewrite the uploder (maybe a observer can do this too) to change the format check and add tif, tiff

Answer (score 0):

You are talking the image uploader within the WYSIWYG, correct? Prattski explains how with a simple module here: http://prattski.com/2011/01/10/magento-allow-other-file-types-in-wysiwyg-editor/

Comment: No, not the WYSIWYG editor.  I mean the product image gallery where you upload base, small, and thumbnail images for the product. I've added a custom type of image which I want to assign an uploaded tiff to, which will be auto excluded from the frontend displays.